# Hash Table : Search vs successor time complexity

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, big-o, time-complexity

In [Skiena's book of algorithm design](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Algorithm_Design_Manual_Text.html?id=TrXd-gxPhVYC), given that the hash table has can have maximum `m` buckets and total number of elements is `n`, the following worse case time complexities are observed:

Search: `O(n)`

Successor: `O(n + m)`

Why are the two different? Doesn't finding successor also in a way involve searching the next element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashing achieves constant-time search at the cost of destroying order.  When I search for an element, I hash it (`O(1)`) and look in the chosen bucket (`O(n)` in the worst case if I scan linearly, as all the other buckets might be empty.)

When I want the next element after a given one, I have no guarantee that it will be in the same bucket.  In fact I have no knowledge about where it is at all.  Since I do not *know* what the successor is yet, I can't hash it to find its bucket.  Instead I am forced to look in each bucket (`O(m)`.)

If I probe items in order when scanning a bucket, I end up also doing a total of linear work in the number of items (`O(n)`).  This results in a total complexity of `O(n + m)`.